# Make a List using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

How can I add to the list with CSS selector or something work.
First of all, I tried this code below.

```
List<WebElement> categories = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=ui-select-choices-row-inner]/span"))
System.out.println(categories.size());
```

And I've got a div class like this

```
<div class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append>
<span ng-bind-html="category.name I highlight: $select.search">Test Pre pro</span>
```

I need this list to make a loop into my automatic test.

Comment: Plz be more specific for what you want to do? What "list to make a loop in my automatic test" suppose to mean?

Answer (score 0):

To create a *List*  and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> categories = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.ui-select-choices-row-inner[uis-transclude-append] > span[ng-bind-html]"))
  System.out.println(categories.size());
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> categories = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-select-choices-row-inner' and @uis-transclude-append]/span[@ng-bind-html]"))
  System.out.println(categories.size());
  ```